Duplicating records by using column delimiter in ArcGIS Pro
In ArcGIS Pro 3.3, I have a shapefile where I need to create duplicate records (while preserving geometry per duplicated record) based on the values in a column. The table is structured similar to below:



ID
gridcode
CWHR
VegType




1228112
5
4M
DFR, MHC, MHW, MRI, PPN, RFR, SMC, WFR


11133
2
5M
DFR, EPN, JPN, LPN, MHC, MHW, MRI, PPN, RFR, SMC, WFR


34802
1
5D
DFR, EPN, JPN, LPN, MHC, MHW, MRI, RFR, SMC, WFR



What I would like to achieve is to make a new record per tree species under the VegType field, and only have that species recorded in the field. Using the first record in the above table as an example, the end result should look like this:



ID
gridcode
CWHR
VegType




1228112
5
4M
DFR


1228112
5
4M
MHC


1228112
5
4M
MHW


1228112
5
4M
MRI


1228112
5
4M
PPN


1228112
5
4M
RFR


1228112
5
4M
SMC


1228112
5
4M
WFR



... and then repeat the process for the next record.
Is this possible?

Try this:

Import the shapefile into an ArcGIS Pro feature class.
Make a copy of the feature class in the same geodatabase
Open a python window (Analysis tab>Geoprocessing group>Python>Python Window)
Use code similar to this:


input_fc=r"Your Path\trees"
in_fields = ["OBJECTID","SHAPE" ,"ID", "gridcode", "CWHR", "VegType"]
output_fc = r"Your Path\trees_1"
out_fields = ["OBJECTID","SHAPE","ID", "gridcode", "CWHR", "VegType"]

data = [list(row) for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_fc, in_fields)]
arcpy.management.TruncateTable(output_fc) 
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(output_fc, out_fields)
for row in data:
    if row[5] is None:
        cursor.insertRow(row)
        continue
    for value in row[5].split(", "):
        row[5]=value
        cursor.insertRow(row)
#clean up
del cursor

If the data must be in a shapefile, then export the output feature class to a shapefile. Here is the test output:


Thank you for the code! It worked like you showed above, though my geometry disappeared. I am working with polygons, and the new feature class has null shape values. I modified the in_fields and out_fields to be: ["OBJECTID","ID", "gridcode", "CWHR", "VegType", "elevation", "SHAPE", "SHAPE_Length", "SHAPE_AREA"]

Try replacing "SHAPE" with "SHAPE@"

That worked! Thank you!
